# iOS - How to disable virtual keyboard auto popup when showing a new div in Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am building an app with Cordova for iOS. I have a button which after clicking will call javascript to show a hidden div. However, on showing that hidden div (there is no input text field in that div but a few checkboxes) I see the iOS virtual keyboard pop up automatically.

I am trying to avoid this keyboard from popping up. I am not sure if that's because some field in the div is catching focus or not. How do I find out which field is on focus from the safari Web Inspector after I click the button. And how do I disable the virtual keyboard from popping up?

Comment: when you are showing hidden div, make all your input fields blur (not focus). $("input").blur(); It will be quick fix to your problem but actually it should not behave like that.

Comment: @UttamSinha This doesn't appear to fix the issue. :(

Comment: @UttamSinha Actually this works - I have another editable field in that div. Once I disable that field the keyboard doesn't pop up. thanks!